# How can I make a class diagram for F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, uml

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with F#.  In C# projects, you can create class diagram files (`*.cd`) to visualize the types in your solution and their dependencies on each other.  Is there anything available like that for F#?

I tried manually creating a `*.cd` in my project but a dialog popped up saying that those diagrams are only supported for C#, C++, and VB.

I also have Resharper, which has a Type Dependency diagram tool, which also does not work with F# projects.

Comment: Why do you need that with F#? Are you using classes extensively? Why?

Comment: I would like to visualize my project spread out over a 2D image rather than as a list of type declarations

Comment: This is one take on this: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/no-uml-diagrams/ .In reality this is much less useful in F# for at least two reasons, `functions` tend to take precedence, and the flow is always linear. But I've seen dependency graphs generated for F# so I assume this is possible somehow.

Comment: I saw that article in looking for an answer.  I see the author's point, but I still want a 2D diagram.

Comment: Ok, so then could you please specify exactly _what_ should be on the diagram? And what bigger problem you would be solving with that diagram?

Comment: The bigger problem is that my data model has two hierarchies in it, and I find that the normal F# way of just looking at class declarations makes one of those not-so-obvious.  The first hierarchy is based on "business rules", such as a Person has an Address has a City.  The second is because I am implementing the Prototype pattern across the first hierarchy, and most types have a Prototype type an Instance type, and an interface that both of those types implement.  See GitHub for more context: https://github.com/JamesFaix/HOA

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking just to visualize your types relation, you can use dotPeek from Resharper.

In dotPeek:

1. Load the dll of your f# project.
2. Select the types you want in the menu on the right.
3. Click on the Inspect/Show Type Dependency Diagram